# Aegir install fails on hostmaster installation

Tags: ubuntu, drush, aegir

I am trying to install manually Aegir on Ubuntu 14.04 VPS backed with Nginx and MariaDB. I have followed:
http://community.aegirproject.org/content/installing/manual/nginx-mariadb-php-fpm-single-server-installation

and modified last command:

```
drush hostmaster-install  nginx.drophost.eu  \
--aegir_host="nginx.drophost.eu" \
--http_service_type="nginx" \
--aegir_db_user="root" \
--aegir_db_pass="dbadmin" \
--aegir_db_port=3306 \
--aegir_db_host="localhost" \
--client_email="contact@drophost.eu" \
--script_user="aegir" \
--web_group="www-data"
```

however install seems to fail on drush connecting to db:

```
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                                                          [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another site with
a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to:
 Drupal version        :  6.31
 Site URI              :  nginx.drophost.eu
 Default theme         :  garland
 Administration        :  garland
 theme
 PHP executable        :  /usr/bin/php
 PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 PHP OS                :  Linux
 Drush version         :  6.2.0
 Drush configuration   :  /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/drushrc.php
                          /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php
 Drush alias files     :  /var/aegir/.drush/server_localhost.alias.drushrc.php /var/aegir/.drush/hostmaster.alias.drushrc.php
                          /var/aegir/.drush/server_master.alias.drushrc.php /var/aegir/.drush/platform_hostmaster.alias.drushrc.php
 Drupal root           :  /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1
 Site path             :  sites/nginx.drophost.eu


Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/themes directory successful.                                           [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/imagecache directory successful.                                 [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/pictures directory successful.                                   [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/locations directory successful.                                  [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/tmp directory successful.                                        [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/css directory successful.                                        [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/ctools directory successful.                                     [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/js directory successful.                                         [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files/images directory successful.                                     [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/files directory successful.                                            [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/modules directory successful.                                          [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/libraries directory successful.                                        [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/private/files directory successful.                                    [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/private/temp directory successful.                                     [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu/private directory successful.                                          [success]
Deleting /var/aegir/hostmaster-6.x-2.1/sites/nginx.drophost.eu directory successful.                                                  [success]
The drush command '@hostmaster provision-verify' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if [error]
you have installed new extensions.
A Drupal installation directory could not be found
```

Answer (score 0):

After switching to 12.04 and mysql-server installation went fine, so it has to be either OS or db issue.